# Ahead, neutral and astern electric switching

Tags: switching

I have a historic barge built in 1936.

During modifications by previous owners, an engine was installed without its hydraulic ahead and astern selector.  Instead, there is a huge lever in the wheel house which has proven to be a trip hazard.

Spares are unobtainable. Working on a limited budget and intelligence.

I have been given an XYD-16, 24V, 250W~500W, Torque: 10NM,Permanent Magnet, Brushed , RPM390, Continuous Current(A):15A~23A, Asynchronous Motor.

I can install it to the job, I think. The barge has both 12V and 24V supply.  I havr  a pair of SW182-116 12V switches left lying around.

My problem is how to arrange the switching. The principal is push the stick forward to go ahead. When the gear is fully engaged a switch on the gear lever stops the current and switches polarity ready for disengagement. The same approach to go astern. I’m at a loss as to how to get the motor to stop at neutral and be ready for the next command either ahead or astern.

Comment: What is [historic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/historic) about your barge?

Comment: Maybe the captain once got into hot water https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoN-jFOHGw0

Comment: DC Motors are not Asynchronous. But you might want 4 positions. Fwd, Brake, Rev, Coast (open)

Comment: Is there a clutch or just a shifter and motor speed control with a reverse solenoid?  Better define the all requirements for motor speed, timing and motor surge currents. Position sensors need a diagram.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking how to get the actuator to drive back to the centre / neutral position when the selector is in neutral? Is it enough to move so that neither the Ahead and Astern limit switches are on? (If not you're going to need a "Neutral" limit switch and some form of memory to remember which side of neutral you are currently located.

Comment: The history of the Barge is she was built for the Leeds Co-op to carry 50t in the hold and to pull two pans as well. Equipped with a 100Hp Crosley engine. Similar barges built at that time had 40hp.  The Asynchronous came from specifications on the web. No clutch. The motor will only do about 3 rpm for ahead from neutral, same for astern. I’m not sure about motor surge current, I assumed it was 25 amps as per specs.  Sensors to be positioned where necessary. I was thinking of some sort of reed switch for neutral. Becoming active as the selectors is shifted ahead or astern.

Comment: What is an "ahead and astern selector"?

Comment: @Hearth, presumably a 3-position version of [this](https://www.megapixl.com/full-ahead-full-astern-and-stop-stock-photo-31552800).

Comment: Can you re-locate the existing lever to a more convenient location?  I think sticking with the present mechanical control would be easier and more reliable than the electric motor system you are proposing.

Comment: What situation causes the trip hazard ? Lack of dead space between off and reversal? If so what are the specs you guess for motor arm speed vs lever position and thus sensor displacement? Normally motor on surge for a DC motor this size is 5 to 8 x max rated current. But breakers need minutes to trip at this peak unless already hot.

Comment: Does the lever operate speed (RPM) as well? Or are there two different levers for direction and speed?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Trip hazards about speed levers are unfortunately common in boats, not only in old ones. I sailed on a boat where a soon-to-be-ex mate broke the lever in full-ahead state, just when approaching a lock gate. The pullpit didn't look good afterwards.

Comment: This IS an electrical design question. Requirements have been clarified in comments. So - I voted for it to remain open.

Comment: @Beet  It would be very helpfuil to copy various relevant points that you have made in comments intop the answer. This helps people currently and in furure get a clear idea of the actual requirtement.

Answer (score 1):

To convert to electric actuator operation becomes quite tricky because of the "neutral" position requirement. The problem is that the system has to keep track (memory) of which side of neutral the actuator is so that it knows how to get back.

The sketch below shows how complex this becomes and I'm not sure that it covers all conditions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwUB62.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An electrical actuator control system.*

Since the problem seems to be one of a trip hazard I recommend that you come up with a mechanical fix. This could be a double cable connection (much like the helm-rudder connection on some boats) or a flexible hydraulic tube connection. Either of these could be routed out of the way. Good design will make this more reliable than an electrical solution which may fail with serious consequences.

[image]

*Figure 2. A helm and rudder cable system. Image source: [SplashMaritime](http://www.splashmaritime.com.au/Marops/data/text/Steertex/Stertex.htm).

A stainless steel stranded wire running over a series of brass pulleys would look pretty and be a whole lot simpler to troubleshoot than the circuit of Figure 1.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm just not familiar with barge transmissions that have speed and direction on a helm.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I'm just using the helm control gear as an example of the mechanism. I'm not suggesting integration of the speed control.

Comment: If the lever is hard to turn maybe a power assisted lever with a strain gauge for feedback to assist on torque above some threshold integrated then no position sense is needed. Just power steering of the transmission lever with a rotor that limits lever travel in each direction

Comment: Your comment on a potential  hazard is why I posted the question. The cable method has been considered, however the gear mechanism is too heavy. From the manual the slave cylinder operates at 20 atmospheres! I have tried a couple of hydraulics engineers in my travels, not interested.  Your comment on a power assisted lever is what I was trying to create